# GCC preprocessor output and compilation in one pass

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to generate preprocessor output and compilation in one step with GCC?

Something like:

```
gcc -E -c main.cc -o main.o
```

that would generate main.o and main.i

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.

Look at `gcc` `-save-temps` option.

It compiles the source file and saves the result of the preprocessing in a `.i` file. (It also saves the result of the assembler phase to a `.s` file).

```
gcc -save-temps -c main.cc -o main.o
```

will generate `main.o` but also `main.i` and `main.s`.

`main.i` is the result of the preprocessing.

Comment: my gcc-based compiler only saves the `.s` file

Answer (score 7):

No, not with `-E` itself, the `-s`, `-c` and `-E` options are called "stop" options. They actually halt the process at a specific point so you can't keep going.

If you want to do that, you have to do it in two passes, or use `-save-temps` to keep copies of the temporary files normally deleted during compilation.

From the `gcc` manpage, stuff discussing `-E` (slightly paraphrased):

> If you only want some of the stages of compilation, you can use -x (or filename suffixes) to tell gcc where to start, and one of the options -c, -S, or -E to say where gcc is to stop.  Note that some combinations (for example, -x cpp-output -E) instruct gcc to do nothing at all.
>
> -E means: stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output (or to the output file if -o is specified).
>
> If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing.

And a description of `-save-temps`:

> **-save-temps**
>
> Store the usual "temporary" intermediate files permanently; place them in the current directory and name them based on the source file.
>
> Thus, compiling foo.c with -c -save-temps would produce files foo.i and foo.s, as well as foo.o.
>
> This creates a preprocessed foo.i output file even though the compiler now normally uses an integrated preprocessor.