# GCC preprocessor output and compilation in one pass, v2

Tags: c++, gcc, preprocessor

As [this question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041381/gcc-preprocessor-output-and-compilation-in-one-pass), I need a way to do

`gcc -E -c main.cc -o main.o`

On my compiler, from QNX but based on `gcc 4.4.2`, using `-save-temps` only gives me the assembly files (and no preprocessor files).

If I add `-E` like in the command above, the preprocessor output will be saved to `main.o`.

I need a solution that does both compilation AND outputs the preprocessor in one invocation of `gcc` with the above constraints.

Comment: XY problem. What's the problem using two steps?

Comment: @Olaf taking twice as long. The preprocessor is already invoked during compilation so why shouldn't this be possible?

Comment: That's not the same. On modern compilers there are not necessarily two distinct passes for preprocessing and compilation. And if there are two phases you most likely don't loose much performance. However, if you are after speeding up compilation, use a build tool; it will save much more time than what you seem to worry about.

Comment: according to [this site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) regarding `-E` option: `(...) and one of the options -c, -S, or -E to say where gcc is to stop` - "to stop" does not leave much hope in doing that in one step.

Comment: @Adrian Speaking generally: It's quite possible that in normal compilation there is no *separate* preprocessing step. So while it of course is a solvable programming problem, nobody has implemented a 1-step solution to your problem, because internally it is 2 steps anyway.

Comment: Adrian - you said `taking twice as long` - did you really measure it? I mean, measure the time that gcc took to finish two phases? or do you just refer to the fact that you have to run it twice with two commandlines to run?

Comment: Partly for efficiency and partly for debugging information for macros GCC doesn't do preprocessing in separate steps. As far as I know.

Comment: @ZanLynx It provides an option to save the preprocessor output in a file. Doesn't that suggest that it generates this intermediate form internally, even if it's not a separate step? That's consistent with the OP's goal -- he wants to get that file even while it continues to perform the other phases of compilation.

Comment: @Barmar: It generates that as a special favor when it is asked. When it continues on normally, it never generates a text form. It is parsing the file into in-memory syntax trees from preprocessing and C/C++ parsing at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar: The GNU C-preprocessor `gpp` is not the same as the C compiler which includes the preprocessor. Note that `gcc` and `g++` are actually frontend for various backend tools, including gpp, the C compiler (cc1 IIRC), the C++ compiler, Ada, Fortran, the linker, etc. The standard does not mandate a seperate preprocessor, but explicitly allows compilation stages to be done in one pass **as long they have the same result**.

Comment: @Olaf This question has little to do with the standard, since it also doesn't say anything about options to view the intermediate stages.

Comment: @Barmar: It very well has! OP clearly assumes there have to be seperate stages, which the standard does not mandate. And last time I checked, the C-tag was about standard C.

Comment: @Olaf His question is about implementation-specific options like `-E` and `--save-temps`. These options work despite the standard not requiring them.

Comment: @Olaf I don't see the C tag, I see `gcc`.

Comment: @barmer: Read the comments and between the lines. and `s/C/C++/`

Comment: @Olaf The C and C++ standards do specify separate stages, they are called "phases of translation". See section [lex.phases] of C++14.

Comment: @M.M: Where did I say different? At least the C standard also states they need not be implemented sepereately as described, but can be integrated. Which every modern compiler does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On my compiler, from QNX but based on gcc 4.4.2, using -save-temps only gives me the assembly files (and no preprocessor files).

I can't verify that for such an old version of GCC, or any QNX variant. Certainly
all mainline GCC versions at least as old as 4.7 respect `... -c -save-temps foo.c`
by saving the preprocessed source in `foo.i` and the assembly in `foo.s`.

But if that's the case with your QNX GCC 4.4.2, there's a workaround.

From your comments it appears that your objection to invoking the
compiler twice is that you do not want time to be wasted in
preprocessing the source twice. But you can invoke the compiler twice, once to do the preprocessing *only*,
and again to do the compiling *only*, so I presume that would be a satisfactory solution.

Your wished-for command line:

```
gcc -E -c main.cc -o main.o
```

shows a C++ source file being given to the C compiler. I assume that's a slip.
The recipes for the outcome you're after are symmetrically different for
C and for C++.

For C you want:

```
gcc -E main.c > main.i && gcc -c -o main.o main.i
```

For C++ you want:

```
g++ -E main.cc > main.ii && g++ -c -o main.o main.ii
```

This writes the preprocessed C[C++] output that you want to save to
`main.i[.ii]` and then passes that preprocessed output to the compiler
again for C[C++] compilation. `gcc[g++]` recognizes the file
extension `.i[.ii]` as denoting *C[C++] source code that should not be preprocessed*.
See [3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html);
so it will not attempt to preprocess the source again.

This solution also has the merit of not generating the assembly files, which
you don't want.